# Case statement or Subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a select query but I need to filter my result out only if it meets certain criteria other than that I still want to see remaining.

I have tried including where (case when x=y and a=b then =1 else 0 end)=1 but this returns the data that I don't want to include.

```
 gl.col1,
 gl.col2,
 gl.voucher_type,
 gl.reference_serie Reference_Series,
 .
 .
 .
from table1 gl

where (case 
         when gl.voucher_type = '0' and gl.reference_serie='PUR ORDER' 
                  then 1 ELSE 0 end) =1
```

Reason being is if you look at the code I want to exclude anything that is a voucher type 0 and reference serie is 'PUR ORDER' but let's say if there is a voucher type 0 but a different reference serie I want to see it. 
I know my case has a = instead of <> but this is to demonstrate what I'm trying to find in order to exclude it.

I don't have any errors, I'm just unsure of next steps and if CASE statement is the right approach. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want to avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  Here are two simple alternatives:

```
where not (gl.voucher_type = '0' and gl.reference_serie = 'PUR ORDER')

where gl.voucher_type <> '0' or gl.reference_serie <> 'PUR ORDER'
```

Note that these filter out `NULL` values -- which your form does not.  The logic can easily be adjusted to handle that, if the columns have `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've re-written the logic and sticked with simple where clause. Think I tried to over complicate the issue for myself. Thanks again Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `case-when`:

```sql
 gl.col1,
 gl.col2,
 gl.voucher_type,
 gl.reference_serie Reference_Series,
 .
 .
 .
from table1 gl

where gl.voucher_type = '0' and gl.reference_serie='PUR ORDER'
```